# Why Reactive programming application( vert.x) is faster than single thread lock free , no-blocking java application?

Tags: java, multithreading, http, reactive-programming, vert.x

I recently tested a simple HTTP server using vert.x( java based) I was amazed by the throughput and api latency of http server, it is blazingly fast.

The same piece of code of http-server was run on java application with single thread, lock free and non-blocking. Performance was less than 1/3rd of vert.x one.

What I do not understand is, what is the core technical difference that the vert.x outperforms non-reactive java application ?

STATS :

Testing was done using Jmeter. Both jmeter and application was run on same machine- jmeter consuming cpu 25-50%, app consuming cpu 20-30% .
All the tests were run for 5 minutes.

1. Spring boot  with 1 tomcat worker thread :

Jmeter with 1 client thread bombarding request (throughout :3474 per sec):
[image]

Jmeter with 50 client thread bombarding request concurrently (throughout :4285 per sec):
[image]

2. Vert.x ( java based ) with only 1 vertical ( http processor vertical ) – meaning only 1 processor thread

Jmeter with 1 client thread bombarding request (throughout :9382 per sec) :
 [image]

Jmeter with 50 client threads bombarding requests concurrently (throughout :20785 per sec):
 [image]

Comment: Profile both the apps and look at the thread dump. That will get give a clue. You will need to provide numbers to get feedback.

Answer (score 6):

There are many reasons for that.
First one is that you compare single threaded bare Java application with Vertx, which is [actually multithreaded](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_reactor_and_multi_reactor).
Second one is how you use lock free data structures. [Lock free doesn't necessarily means "faster in all conditions"](http://preshing.com/20111118/locks-arent-slow-lock-contention-is/).
Third, and I think that's the main point, some of the best Red Hat developers contributed to Vertx development. You can examine the [source code](https://github.com/eclipse/vert.x) and see some very smart use of buffers, for example. It's a bit too much to expect from a example project to outperform such a framework from the first shot. If you're interested in some alternatives, check [Rapidoid](https://github.com/rapidoid/rapidoid) performance, which should be on par with Vertx.

Comment: Thanks Alexey for the comment!

#1 - I understand vertx is multi-threaded with 1 event-loop thread per core. I ran this on 4 core machine. Spring boot didn't scale event having 4 or more threads.
#2 - agreed
#3 - will check on this

Comment: Did you use SpringBoot with Jetty or Undertow? Also, if you're comparing to Spring ecosystem, try WebFlux. But frankly, Vertx is just fast :)